# Notice undefined_index, using a select with two tables to access the fields of both tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I'm trying to do a search system that involves two tables "News & Pages".

**My news table:**

[image]

**My pages table**

[image]

When user write a word and submit form I´ll do a select to search that word WHERE title and content of my tables news and pages are LIKE that word.

So I want to select my two tables to have acess to fields of that two tables because I want to show query results in a list.

Im using this sql statment:

```
SELECT id_news, thumb, title, content, date, statuss, category FROM news
      WHERE statuss = '%e%' AND title LIKE '%e%' OR content LIKE '%e%' 
UNION 
SELECT id_pag, title_pag, content_pag, link, NULL, NULL, NULL FROM pages
      WHERE title_pag LIKE '%e%' OR content_pag LIKE '%e%' LIMIT 0,10
```

And I'm getting this:

[image]

**So the problem is:** I want to show results in a list, and I dont want to have only access to my fields of news, I also want to acess my table pages columns.

But Im just having acess to my news table columns, when I do:

```
if($result['id_pag'] != ''){
    echo '<a href="'.BASE.$result['link'].'">'.$result['title_pag'].'</a>';
 }
```

I get this notice: Notice: Undefined index: id_pag

**This is my code:**

```
echo '<ul class="searchlist">';

    $read = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id_news, thumb, title, content, date, statuss, category FROM news
                                WHERE statuss = ? AND title LIKE ? OR content LIKE ? 
                           UNION 
                           SELECT id_pag, title_pag, content_pag, link, NULL, NULL, NULL FROM pages
                                WHERE title_pag LIKE ? OR content_pag LIKE ? LIMIT 0,10 ");
    $read->bindValue(1, '1');
    $read->bindValue(2, "%search%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $read->bindValue(3, "%$search%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $read->bindValue(4, "%$search%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $read->bindValue(5, "%$search%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $read->execute();   

    while ($result = $read->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){                   
        echo '<li>';
            if($result['id_news'] != ''){
                echo '<a href="#">';
                    echo '<img src="'.BASE.'/uploads/news/'.$result['thumb'].'"/>';
                echo '</a>';
            }
            if($result['id_pag'] != ''){
                echo '<a href="'.BASE.$result['link'].'">'.$result['title_pag'].'</a>';
            }
        echo '</li>';
    }
echo ' </ul>';
```

Can you please give me a help?

Comment: You've got to use the column names of the first select of an `UNION`. To distinguish from which part of the union your rows are, add a column with i.e. `SELECT, ..., 'news' as source ...` in the first and `SELECT ..., 'pages' ...` in the second one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `UNION` the column names are used from the first `SELECT` and the other names are lost..

If you need to differentiate between the two sets, you could add a `type` column to the query like this:

```
SELECT 'news' `type`, id_news, thumb, title, content, date, statuss, category 
  FROM news
 WHERE statuss = '%e%' AND title LIKE '%e%' OR content LIKE '%e%' 
 UNION 
SELECT 'pages', id_pag, title_pag, content_pag, link, NULL, NULL, NULL 
  FROM pages
 WHERE title_pag LIKE '%e%' OR content_pag LIKE '%e%' LIMIT 0,10
```

Then you can use `$result['type']` as your `if` condition.

However, your two result sets are so wildly different that I would just run two queries. It looks super hacky as is.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, it worked! And probably I´ll follow your tip!